# How to show all asp: drop-down items in bold when using bootstrap 3 and form-control class on drop down list

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-control

I am working on a web-forms based project in asp.net 4.6 and using bootstrap3. I want to show all asp: drop-down items in bold.

I have form-control class applied to asp:drop down list

Comment: Default ASP.Net DropDownList renders as ***select*** tag, so is not possible unless you use third-party one like [Telerik DropDownList](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) or create a Server Control by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you can't just jam a `<b>` tag in there as an asp drop down item is converted to a `<select>` with the relevant `<option>`. You can however use CSS to style your `<select>` tags. Something like this.

```css
select{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>My great option 1</option>
  <option>My great option 2</option>
  <option>My great option 3</option>
  <option>My great option 4</option>
  <option>My great option 5</option>
</select>
```

Modify this to apply only to your specific class name, or only to the options rather than everything.

Comment: You're right Rob, I applied font-weight:bolder on "Options" class

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer using the controls on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this application wide by adding

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
     /*makes* the asp drop down text bolder*/
    option {
        font-weight:bolder !important;
    }
</style>
```

to the site.master